# Microsoft Report Builder - Row totals percent of column total

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report-builder2.0

I'd really appreciate some help with Report Builder. As seen below, I have a report that shows the number of items. In my SQL query I have used a CASE statement to tag some of the items with a y or a n.

What I want to do is add a calculated cell that sums all the values of the items tagged with y and divide by the total and * 100 to find the percent of the rows tagged y of the total amount.

Answer looking for is -

```
Apple | Y | 100
Pear  | Y | 200
Orange| N | 500
Total |     800

Percent of Ys =  37.5% (100+200/800*100)
```

I'm new to report builder so please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add two more columns to your query, using similar logic as your CASE statement for the Y/N column. The first column is populated with the value only when the condition for "Y" is true, otherwise it is zero. The second column is populated with the value only when the condition for "N" is true, otherwise it is zero. This would give you a result set similar to this:

```
            All     Y     N

Apple | Y | 100 | 100 |   0
Pear  | Y | 200 | 200 |   0
Orange| N | 500 |   0 | 500
Total |     800 | 300 | 500
```

Then your calculation is something like this:

```
Percent of Ys = (Sum(Y) / Sum(All)) * 100
```

i.e.

```
Percent of Ys = (300 / 800) * 100 = 37.5%
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, I can't find a way to add this to my sql query.  It wont let me reference a column created in a case statement?  Could you tell me a way to do this in SQL?  Mnay thanks.

Comment: You can't reference the column you have already created, you need to repeat the CASE logic in the new columns

Comment: Ahh okay.  Thanks alot, I think I've cracked it:)